# What's the best way to compare 2 maps and get the difference?

Tags: java, dictionary, equals

If I've got 2 maps as follows:

```
Map<Long, Apple> map1;
Map<Long, Apple> map2;
```

and `Apple` as `equals` method overridden, I can compare the 2 maps using:

```
map1.equals(map2);
```

If they are not equal (if above is `false`), what is the best way to get the differences between them? Differences could be:

1. Keys are different
2. Keys are the same but values are different

**Update:**

### **SOLUTION**

I found out that `com.google.common.collect.MapDifference` [1] can be used to find the differences in both keys and values

[1] https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html

Comment: There is any number of ways to do this, it entirely depends on how you want to view or display the differences. If you just care about the type of difference (not the value) the use an [ENUM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and return a list with the value of each ENUM according to the difference. As for how you get the differences, just create a new method, it doesn't need to be part of the Apple class.

Comment: The best way to do this depends on what output you want.  Do you want just a `Set<Long>` that includes all the keys that are either in one map but not the other, or have different associate values in the two maps?  Or do you need to see all the associated values as well?

Comment: I think we need more definition for the expected behavior. As one example scenario, consider if both maps have "key1", but map1 has "valueA", while map2 has "valueB". How should that be represented as a difference? You could capture results that represent something like: _"valueA and valueB were collisions, but didn't track which key, or which map had which value"_, or _"key1 had different values in each map: valueA, valueB"_, or  _"map1 had key1->valueA, and map2 had key1->valueB"_. There are surely other variations and scenarios to consider for what constitutes a difference between maps.

Comment: What does "best" mean? Less lines of code? Faster? Easy to understand? For who?

Comment: The solution is to use  `com.google.common.collect.MapDifference` which gets the differences between keys and values without manual evaluation. The question stated the differences could be keys and values, which means I was looking for a solution to list the differences of both.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **Set**, as it allows you to remove and retain elements-

```
Set<String> entry = take a copy of all starting entries
Set<String> exit = take a copy of all last entries

entry.removeAll(exit) 
- leaves only entries in entry point that are only in entry Set, not in exit Set

entry.retainAll(exit) 
- leaves only entries that are in both sets
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rishav I found out that the solution is to use  `com.google.common.collect.MapDifference` which gets the differences between keys and values without manual evaluation.